How to call a python API protected by XSUAA?
I followed the following tutorial ( https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/btp-cf-buildpacks-python-create.html ). When I just call the backend via a browser it just works.
I modified the backend so that it uses CORS, this works, I tested it.
Everything is hosted in the same CF space.
When I call the backend from postman, I get the following response:
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" />
        <script>
            document.cookie="fragmentAfterLogin="+encodeURIComponent(location.hash)+";path=/;";document.cookie="locationAfterLogin="+encodeURIComponent(location.href.split('#')[0].split(location.host)[1])+";path=/;";document.cookie="signature=jNVOmEfTxSQoOY4mBOoglXKb%2BRg%3D;path=/;";location="https://1163ae6d-9f9a-4ae0-839f-a8261c3ca5b9.authentication.sap.hana.ondemand.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=sb-myapp!t14775&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fweb-triumphant-nyala-yk.cfapps.sap.hana.ondemand.com%2Flogin%2Fcallback"
        </script>
    </head>

</html>

I know that I probably redacted too much, but I don't care.
I build a simple SAPUI5 website, which I connected to same XSUAA service as the backend but it didn't work either.
Any ideas ?
Thank you for your time and help!!!
